# insert certain date and time into a date format column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO pk_prodinfor (
    prod_id
    ,qtypotb
    ,target_wt
    ,balance_wt
    ,package_cat
    ,latest
    ,set_by
    ,set_time
    ,process_code
    ,tolocation
    ,package_size
    )
VALUES (
    '54-62-14479-064G'
    ,6480
    ,13
    ,.5
    ,'PC'
    ,1
    ,'30165'
    ,2018 - 02 - 09
    ,'F'
    ,'FG'
    ,''
    )
```

Hi all, how to insert datetime 2018-02-09 11:00:01 into a DATE format in sql?
Please help.

SQL above gives error.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: did u say u want to insert as ` date` format from `datetime` ? whats the data type  of destination column

Comment: In standard SQL you would need to use `date '2018-02-09'` to supply a proper date literal or `timestamp '2018-02-09 11:00:01'` for a timestamp (=date and time) literal

Comment: What error you got? You miss the quotes for the date, also you cant save datetime into a date column.

Answer (score 2):

[Date/time literals should be quoted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql)

Edit, [Even in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062)

> datetime constants are represented by using character date values in specific formats, enclosed in single quotation marks.

```
values('54-62-14479-064G',6480,13,.5,'PC',1,'30165', '2018-02-09 11:00:01','F','FG','')
```

Comment: i dont think we can set like this.

Comment: Add a semi-colon

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: oops, copy paste fail